# Handle form submission event with Javascript, avoid "Form Processed"

Tags: javascript, dom-events, lotus-domino

I have a text box and Javascript attached to a button. I have the `onkeyup` event linked to the same method as the button.

I want to be able to type in the text box and hit enter and execute my Javascript. Instead, lotus thinks I want to submit a form, hijacks what I am doing, and returns "Form Processed". It is very obnoxious.

What can I do to avoid Lotus doing this?

Comment: http://www.itechies.net/dev/code-samples-tutorials-and-examples/Html/details_faq-sbres_id-30.htm

Comment: I still get the form processed

Comment: It's not Lotus that is doing it.  It is the browser.

Comment: How can it be the browser? I have no <form> elements, and if I use this code on another non-domino server, why does it work?

Comment: If your code is entered in a Domino Form design element then Domino does insert a <form> tag because, well... that's what Domino Forms are supposed to do.  If you don't need a submit, then use a Domino Page design element instead of a Form.

Comment: ahhh. I did not know the difference. Thank you. But now I have moved my code to a Domino page and it just requests the same url with the value of my text box appended. It ignores my onkeydown Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't ever want to do a standard submit to Domino, then use a Page design element instead of a Form.

But if you do want to submit a standard Domino form, you can set the onSubmit event on the form to false in order to stop the browser from doing automatic submits.  But you won't be able to use a simple submit button if you do that.  You will have to explicitly call document.forms[0].submit().

Comment: I have 'return false;' in the onSubmit. It does not change anything.

Comment: Let me be more clear, I am not using a form. I literally have pass-though HTML with <input type="text" id ="myTextBox">.

Comment: Do you have the passthru HTML on a Domino Form, or on a Domino Page?  Note that I edited my answer above as more information has been provided.

Comment: ahhh. I did not know the difference. Thank you. But now I have moved my code to a Domino page and it just requests the same url with the value of my text box appended. It ignores my onkeydown Javascript

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm not following your meaning.  What do you mean by "it just requests the same url with the vlaue of my text box appended."?  When does that happen?  Is it doing that when the user clicks the Enter key in the text field?  Have you looked at the page source in the browser? Is Domino adding anything in the head or body of the HTML that you do not expect to see?

Comment: I realized that I need some elements that are only allowed in a domino form. However this post helped me realize that I can just add </form> to the very top of my page to kill the native domino form. So I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Also... You said above that you are using passthru HTML, so here's another question: are you using any of Domino's automatic formatting and processing features, or are you only using passthru HTML for the entire content of the Page?  If so, there is a Content Type setting that you can set on the Page properties.  The default is Notes, but you could change it to HTML.  If you do that, you won't even have to mark your code as passthru, because everything is treated that way. That should minimize what the Domino server does on its own accord.

Comment: Yes closing the Domino form tag is an old trick. I think most of us try to avoid that these days, but I have to admit... I've done even sneakier things, especially in the earlier releases when we had a lot fewer ways to control Domino's behavior. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a function that handles the submit event for that form and have it return false.

The easiest way to do this is to add this attribute to your form tag

```
 <form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: Lotus has a onSubmit event handler, but no matter what I do (return false, run my method, etc) it does not prevent my problem.

Comment: I guess Lotus might be different than other browsers. You can also try event.stopPropagation() inside the onSumbit function. "event" is the variable name for the event.

Comment: Lotus is not a browser. It is a Lotus Domino Web Server.

Comment: I was just working off the (wrong) assumption that it probably behaved similar to other javascript environments. You might also try event.preventDefault().